# How to load csv file if ready file exists using azure datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i have a filename.ready and filename.csv in azure fileshare in single folder. Using azure data factory i need to check for ready file if ready file exists i need to load csv file into azure data lake container where i need to place the file according to the name of the file into particular folder name, inside the datalake container there will be many folders so i need to place to check whether filename = folder name then place the file in particular folder. how to perform this activity in azure data factory. what all activities are required and how to write/Add dynamic content

Comment: Does my answer achieve your requirement?

Comment: i have modified the requirement can you please help me out

Comment: Two things that need to be clarified : 1. Your single folder in fileshare only has two files(.ready and .csv) and their file name is same, right? 2. If your particular folder doesn't exist in data lake, what to do? create it?

Comment: clarifications. 1.yes it will have two files.  2. actually there will be pre existing folders in datalake so depending on the name of the file matching the folder the file will be placed.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the step:

1. create two variables named folderName and fileName.
2. use GetMetadata activity to get the file list in your file share.

[image]

3. get the .ready file by Filter activity.

   Item:`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

   Condition:`@contains(item().name,'.ready')`
4. loop Filter activity's output by ForEach activity.

   Items:`@activity('Filter1').output.Value`
   [image]
5. within ForEach activity, set folderName variable first.

   Value:`@split(item().name,'.')[0]`
   [image]
6. use GetMetaData activity to check whether particular folder exists.
   [image]

   Dataset setting:
   [image]
   [image]
7. set fileName variable.
   Value:`@replace(item().name,'.ready','.csv')`
8. create a If Condition activity to decide whether to copy .csv file.
   Expression: `@activity('Get Metadata2').output.exists`
9. In true case of If Condition activity, create a Copy Data activity to copy .csv file.

   Setting of Copy Data activity:
   [image]

   [image]

   Setting of Source Dataset:
   [image]
   [image]

   Setting of Sink Dataset:
   [image]
   [image]